# Making a display picture required

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, validation

I have a dynamically generated form that loads the display pic of an item in my database into an  tag when the form is loaded, with the  tag serving as an image preview of the current display image.

EDIT: The form is generated when the user selects an item: Category->Subcategory->Item-> form is generated containing the item details and display pic.What i'm trying to do in this case is to prevent the user from editing the data( accidentally or intentionally deleting the display pic without replacing it with another one), resulting in a situation where the item does not have a display pic.

I would like to make the display pic a required element( every item **MUST** have a display pic), and the user cannot submit the form if he deleted the current display pic without replacing it with another one.

To do this, i have tried using jQUery validate, and the required rule on the file input element.However, doing this requires the user to upload a new image every time the form is generated, even if he leaves the current display pic untouched.

PHP form code:

```
//Fetches the item DP
$fetchdp=$cxn->prepare("SELECT `ItemDP` FROM `Items` WHERE `BusinessID`=:bizid AND `ItemID`=:itemid");
$fetchdp->bindValue(":bizid",$bizid);
$fetchdp->bindValue(":itemid",$itemid);
$fetchdp->execute();
while($getdp=$fetchdp->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $dp=$getdp["ItemDP"];
}

//Input and preview for Display Pic
echo"<div class='BizEditItemDetails' >";
    echo"<label for='BizEditItemFileDP'>Upload Image[DP] &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp(Max Size:2MB)</label>";
    echo"<input type='file' class='BizEditItemInput' id='BizEditItemFileDP' name='BizEditItemFileDP' />";
    echo"<input type='button' id=ImageCancelDP name=ImageCancelDP class='ImageCancelButton' value='Cancel'>";
    echo"<span></span>";
    echo"<br>";
    echo"<img id=ImagePreviewDP name=ImagePreviewDP class='ImagePreview' src=".$dp." > ";
    echo"<input type='hidden' id=DisplayDeleteItemID name=DisplayDeleteItemID value=$itemid>";
    echo"<input type='hidden' id=DisplayDeleteItemPicID name=DisplayDeleteItemPicID value=$itempicid>";
    echo"<input type='hidden' id=DisplayDeleteFilePath name=DisplayDeleteFilePath value=".$dp." >";
    echo"<input type='button' id=DisplayDelete name=DisplayDelete class='ImageDeleteButton' value='Delete Picture'>";
    echo"<br>";
echo"</div>";
```

jQuery code:

```
  //more code above
  BizEditItemFileDP:{
    required:true
},
```

How do i thus make the display pic "required" without using the required rule?I've been stuck on this for ages and can't seem to make anything work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you use Javascript to determine if a user added a picture or not? What is when the user has no JS?
I would check this in PHPbut I dont know what Framework you're using.

Comment: i'm not trying to determine if he has added a picture? I'm trying to make it such that he is unable to delete a picture without replacing it. I've edited the question to clarify it a little. I apologise if i misunderstood what you wanted to say.

Comment: OK. So its like that. There is a picture box where a default picture is inside. If the user deletes the picture and wants to save the profil there should be an error saying you cant have no profil picture, right? Still: I would do this serverside. If that is still not the thing you want, then I am sorry but I do not understand you correctly.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i mean.I'm just looking for a way to implement this profile pic check, it doesnt have to be client-side. How would you go about doing it server-side?

Comment: When you POST (or GET, whatever you use) the data to your saving.php (or the same php, dont know about your structure) you could check if the variable of $_POST['img'] is empty or not. But I do not know how to put it there. I dont even know what framework you are using.

Comment: Well then it should be fairly easy. As I said, check your $_POST or $_GET data. If there is something in it you dont like (eg. an empty picture variable) you can tell the user when coming back to this site (or if you want to outsource the saving.php you can `header` back to the former site)